# React router Prompt history push query params change Prompt location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem using react-router Prompt component.

I want to warn users when they reload or leave page except for 1 case when I add query param to the url.

I already did it but when I refresh the page after making changed. I go back to the path "/" not the current page I'm working on.

Example: I'm working on path "create-contract".  Then I want to add query ?screen={screen} if users click on a button.

Now I have "create-contract?screen={screen}" Then if I refresh page and confirm or go back to previous url "create-contract" and refresh.

I will go to path "/". What I think is wrong.

I want it still in the current page when I refresh.

Here the code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        if (shouldBlockNavigation) {
            const existingHandler = window.onbeforeunload;
            window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
                if (existingHandler) existingHandler(event);
                return true;
            };
        } else {
            if (screen) {
                history.push("?screen=" + screen);
            } else {
                history.push(RouteConstant.Contract.CreateContract.path);
            }
        }
        return () => {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        };
    }, [shouldBlockNavigation, screen]);

return (
        <>
            <Prompt
                when={shouldBlockNavigation}
                message="作成中の書類を破棄します。よろしいですか？"
            />
            ...
       </>
)
```

Anyone help me please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no information what is `screen` variable.

Seems for me that after reload it goes to this part:

```
else {
   if (screen) {
      history.push(RouteConstant.Contract.CreateContract.path + "?screen=" + screen);
   } else {
      history.push(RouteConstant.Contract.CreateContract.path); // goes here
   }
}
```

To solve this you can try to get current location, parse it, and if it contains `?screen=screen` get screen from this url and use it

To get current location, you can use `useLocation()` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: Thank you for answer my question.

No. when reload it go to case if (shouldBlockNavigation).
"screen" variable just a number 1, 2, 3. 
I try not to show the alert if I click on a button that add the query such as "?screen=1".
But after that if I reload the page it will go to the path "/" not the current path I'm working on